Date stamp gets updated when copying a file with an old date, to USB flash drive, but date stamp is preserved when copying the file to the same drive?
Date stamp gets updated when copying a file with an old date, to USB flash drive, but date stamp is preserved when copying the file to the same drive?
So you see this directory C:\zet has two files.
One with a date stamp of 1970, that's the file (IMG_1970...jpg). (Why the date stamp is so old I don't know because the file is actually created in 2016 but anyhow. Note that the year in the filename happens to match the date stamp).
The other file is a video from 2022 which as we will see, copies fine to USB flash drive.
C:\>dir c:\zet
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of c:\zet

2024-12-14  23:51    <DIR>          .
2024-12-14  23:51    <DIR>          ..
1970-01-02  06:16         2,222,947 IMG_19700102_061650.jpg
2022-06-15  06:15         3,769,884 VID_20220615_071520306.mp4
               2 File(s)      5,992,831 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  818,724,679,680 bytes free

Here is the directory H:\zet on my USB drive.  As you see it's currently empty. Ready for me to demonstrate the issue.
C:\>dir h:\zet
 Volume in drive H is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 0085-95C7

 Directory of h:\zet

2024-12-14  23:50    <DIR>          .
2024-12-14  23:50    <DIR>          ..
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  3,198,971,805,696 bytes free

I copy the video file onto the USB flash drive and show the file, and you see the date stamp is preserved, it was 2022 and that year is preserved in the date stamp.
C:\>copy c:\zet\VID_20220615_071520306.mp4 h:\zet
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>dir h:\zet
 Volume in drive H is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 0085-95C7

 Directory of h:\zet

2024-12-14  23:50    <DIR>          .
2024-12-14  23:50    <DIR>          ..
2022-06-15  06:15         3,769,884 VID_20220615_071520306.mp4
               1 File(s)      3,769,884 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  3,198,967,873,536 bytes free

But not see what happens when I copy the file with the 1970 date stamp, to the USB drive.
C:\>copy c:\zet\IMG_19700102_061650.jpg h:\zet
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>dir h:\zet
 Volume in drive H is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 0085-95C7

 Directory of h:\zet

2024-12-14  23:50    <DIR>          .
2024-12-14  23:50    <DIR>          ..
2022-06-15  06:15         3,769,884 VID_20220615_071520306.mp4
2024-12-14  23:51         2,222,947 IMG_19700102_061650.jpg
               2 File(s)      5,992,831 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  3,198,965,514,240 bytes free

See from above, that the file when copied to H:, gets an update date stamp to today's date, today's year 2024. The year 1970 didn't get preserved, the date just got updated to the current date/time!
Notice though if I copy that file that has the old date stamp, to another location on C:, so the same drive.
Then the date stamp is preserved.
C:\>md zet2

C:\>copy c:\zet\IMG_19700102_061650.jpg c:\zet2
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\>dir c:\zet2
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of c:\zet2

2024-12-14  23:53    <DIR>          .
2024-12-14  23:53    <DIR>          ..
1970-01-02  06:16         2,222,947 IMG_19700102_061650.jpg
               1 File(s)      2,222,947 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  818,721,378,304 bytes free

C:\>cd zet

C:\zet>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4645-5DCE

 Directory of C:\zet

2024-12-14  23:51    <DIR>          .
2024-12-14  23:51    <DIR>          ..
1970-01-02  06:16         2,222,947 IMG_19700102_061650.jpg
2022-06-15  06:15         3,769,884 VID_20220615_071520306.mp4
               2 File(s)      5,992,831 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  818,720,567,296 bytes free


You're copying the file to a FAT32 filesystem, which has very limited range and resolution for timestamps compared to NTFS.
FAT stores each date/time field (year, month, day, etc) separately and allocates 7 bits for the year, with 0 meaning year 1980 and 127 meaning year 2107, therefore 1970 is outside of the possible range.

Fun fact: 1970-01-01 is time 0 for Unix, which traditionally uses a signed integer number of seconds since that reference point for its timestamps.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem - that's when signed 32-bit time_t will overflow.  MS-DOS being written a decade later picked a different epoch reference point (at least in their filesystem); interesting that they didn't allow negative offsets to let people handle files that had existed since before they got a DOS PC...  (The IBM PC released in August 1981.)

Did FAT12 and FAT16 have the same year encoding?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system says FAT was first introduced in 1977, for NCR 7200 data-entry terminals, running on Intel 8080 based.  But that was an 8-bit variant of it, and perhaps could have used a different year encoding?  According to that wiki article, there was also a Microsoft MDOS for a 8080/Z80 platforms.

The MS-DOS 1.25 source code documents the FAT12 format and says bits 9-15=year-1980; the MS-DOS 4.0 source implies the same limits (capped to 2099), and has the same FAT documentation in INC/DIRENT.INC.

Similarly the Windows XP source code doesn't have any different cases for FAT12/16/32, it just defines a single struct _FAT_DATE for all versions.

You started the "copy" tool to copy a file. This will make one call to the operating system to create a new file, several calls to copy the data, and (possibly) a call to set the creation date.
It is quite possible that the "copy" tool detects that source and destination are the same, and in that case sets the creation date to that of the original file, but not if the destination is on another drive.
Another possible explanation would be that creating a file always sets the creation date to the current date and second. And that a call to change the creation date will fail on a drive that is not connected directly to your computer, so the date stays unchanged. This may be intentional to make sure you don't have files on the volume that were created before the volume was created.
The date stamp isn't part of the file itself, but part of its metadata (like filename, creation date, last changed date), so it isn't preserved but it is intentionally changed from the date where the copy was actually created, to the date where the original file was actually created. So it is quite possible that the "copy" command decided not to change the date back for whatever reason.

In your second paragraph, you write "It is quite possible that the "copy" tool detects that source and destination are the same," <-- the source and destination were never the same. You mean same hard drive.
You write "and in that case sets the creation date to that of the original file, but not if the destination is on another drive."
No. Notice in my question I showed that when the video is copied from C to H, it preserved the date.   Normal behaviour is to preserve the date stamp. You could try it yourself and you would see.

You write "The date stamp isn't part of the file itself, but part of its metadata (like filename, creation date, last changed date), so it isn't preserved but it is intentionally changed from the date where the copy was actually created, to the date where the original file was actually created"
<-- Do you have any evidence that when a file is copied, and the copy of the file has the date of the original file, then do you have any evidence that the date was set twice. First to the current date(which we never see), and then to the date of the source file? (cntd)

(cntd) maybe the meta data is simply written once, and with the date of the source file
